# openCV 2.4.9 windows: InputArray is undefined

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to create a dll wrapper for using openCV in labview. I'm also pretty new with both of them (openCV & Labview). I would like to use the cvTriangulatePoints from labview. For now I've created a hpp file

```
#ifndef __OPENCV_PRECOMP_H__
#define __OPENCV_PRECOMP_H__

#include "cvconfig.h"

#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h"
#include "opencv2/core/internal.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include <vector>

#ifdef HAVE_TEGRA_OPTIMIZATION
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d_tegra.hpp"
#else
#define GET_OPTIMIZED(func) (func)
#endif

#endif
```

(this is the precomp.hpp, it's include in the file triangulate.cpp opencv\sources\modules\calib3d\src) Then my own hpp file:

```
#ifdef WRAPPEROPENCV_EXPORTS
#define WRAPPEROPENCV_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define WRAPPEROPENCV __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

#include "precomp.hpp"

namespace WrapperOpenCv
{
     class WrapperOpenCv
     {
         public: 
            WRAPPEROPENCV_API void cvTriangulatePoints(CvMat* projMatr1, CvMat*      projMatr2, CvMat* projPoints1, CvMat* projPoints2, CvMat* points4D);
            WRAPPEROPENCV_API void cvCorrectMatches(CvMat *F_, CvMat *points1_, CvMat *points2_, CvMat *new_points1, CvMat *new_points2);
            static WRAPPEROPENCV_API void triangulatePoints( InputArray _projMatr1, InputArray _projMatr2, InputArray _projPoints1, InputArray _projPoints2,  OutputArray _points4D )
    };
}
```

With this I should be able to export these methods in labview.(I know I still have to implement the functions in a cpp file). PROBLEM : I have an error on InputArray and OutputArray:

```
Error: identifier "InputArray" is undefined
```

Anybody knows what I should do to fix this ? Thanks for the help

Comment: Please read [this paragraph](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/intro.html#inputarray-and-outputarray) on Input/Output Arrays used in OpenCV and then change your method accordingly.

Comment: You may need to include some headers from core module like mat.hpp etc. Try to include them and try once again.

Comment: @scap3y was right, the documentation says _Normally, you should not care of those intermediate types (and you should not declare variables of those types explicitly)_ and use other data type. _projMatr1 and _projmatr2 are some matrix I obtain by running the program "stereoCalib.exe" that is in the opencv example:

Comment: actually there is only the source code stereo_calib.cpp in sample folder of opencv, and you have to build it. But right now my problem is how to use the value in the yml file generate by stereo_calib. Should I create another question for that ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the namespace:

```
cv::InputArray
```

or

```
...
using namespace cv;
namespace WrapperOpenCv
{
...
```

everything work fine nox